# Memory corruption after GetMem in EnumWindows

Tags: delphi

While enumerating windows by their process ID and also window title I have two implementations of the callback function.

The first uses a fixed size char array as buffer and works fine (as far I can see).

With the other using PChar buffer and allocating it using GetMem I get exceptions on different internal `GetMem` after I leave my GetWindowHandleByPID function.

Where is my error in the second one?

```
TEnumWindowsInfo = record
  ProcessID: DWORD;
  HWND: THandle;
  TitleUp: string;
end;

function GetWindowHandleByPID(const hPID: THandle): THandle;
var
  EI: TEnumWindowsInfo;
begin
  EI.ProcessID := hPID;
  EI.HWND := 0;
  EI.TitleUp := 'BLA';
  EnumWindows(@OnEnumWindowsProc, Integer(@EI));
  Result := EI.HWND;
end;


function OnEnumWindowsProc(Wnd: DWORD; var EI: TEnumWindowsInfo): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  pidMatch, titleMatch: BOOL;
  buf: array [0..255] of Char;
  titleAsUpper: string;
begin
  // check PID: GetWindowThreadProcessID
  pidMatch := true;

  // check window title
  GetWindowText(Wnd, buf, 255);
  titleAsUpper := AnsiUpperCase(buf);
  titleMatch := EI.TitleUp = titleAsUpper;

  Result := not (pidMatch and titleMatch);  // continue if not found

  if not Result then
  begin
    EI.HWND := WND;
  end;
end;

function OnEnumWindowsProc_MEM_CORRUPT(Wnd: DWORD; var EI: TEnumWindowsInfo): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  pidMatch, titleMatch: BOOL;
  buffer: PChar;
  len: Integer;
  titleAsUpper: string;
begin
  // check PID: GetWindowThreadProcessID
  pidMatch := true;

  // check window title
  len := GetWindowTextLength(Wnd) + 1; // +1 -> null-terminated
  if len > 1 then
  begin
    try
      GetMem(buffer, len);
      GetWindowText(Wnd, buffer, len);
      titleAsUpper := AnsiUpperCase(buffer);
    finally
      FreeMem(buffer);
    end;
    titleMatch := EI.TitleUp = titleAsUpper;
  end;

  Result := not (pidMatch and titleMatch);  // continue if not found

  if not Result then
  begin
    EI.HWND := WND;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `OnEnumWindowsProc()`, the buffer you are passing to `GetWindowText()` is allocated sufficiently for the size you are claiming to `GetWindowText()`.  You are allocating 256 `Char`s but claiming 255 `Char`s, which means `GetWindowText()` can retrieve up to 254 `Char`s max, plus the null terminator.  So, there is no chance for corrupting memory.

However, in `OnEnumWindowsProc_MEM_CORRUPT()`, you are not allocating enough memory for the buffer. `GetMem()` operates on bytes, not characters. In Delphi 2009 and later, `GetWindowText()` maps to `GetWindowTextW()`, which means it outputs Unicode UTF-16 text rather than ANSI text. And `Sizeof(Char)` is 2 bytes, not 1 byte as your code is assuming.  So, you are allocating only half of the bytes needed for the buffer, but claiming the full size to `GetWindowText/W()`, and so `GetWindowText/W()` ends up overflowing your buffer, corrupting memory.  To fix that, you need to multiple the allocated size by `SizeOf(Char)`:

```pascal
GetMem(buffer, len * SizeOf(Char));
```

Personally, I would not use `GetMem()` for this kind of code, I would use a dynamic `Char` array, or even a `String` instead, eg:

```pascal
function OnEnumWindowsProc_MEM_CORRUPT(Wnd: DWORD; var EI: TEnumWindowsInfo): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  ...
  buffer: array of Char; // or String
  len: Integer;
  ...
begin
  ...

  len := GetWindowTextLength(Wnd);
  if len > 0 then
  begin
    // for a Char array:
    Inc(len);
    SetLength(buffer, len);
    GetWindowText(Wnd, PChar(buffer), len);

    // for a String:
    SetLength(buffer, len);
    GetWindowText(Wnd, PChar(buffer), len+1);

    ...
  end;

  ...
end;
```

---

On a side note:

When calling `EnumWindows()`, you should use `LPARAM(...)` instead of `Integer(...)` when type-casting the `@EI` address in the 2nd parameter, otherwise your code will not work correctly if compiled for a 64bit executable.

Also, you don't need to use `AnsiUpperCase()` followed by `operator=` to compare two strings case-insensitively.  The RTL has functions for that purpose, such as `SysUtils.SameText()`, eg:

```pascal
titleMatch := SameText(buffer, EI.TitleUp);
```

Comment: yes, its Delphi 10.2. Always these problems because of copying old forum code :-D Thanks also for the LPARAM hint, I will change to that. Interestingly with integer it is working in x64, but maybe only luck.

Comment: @casiosmu yes, it is only luck, since casting to `Integer` will chop off the high 32 bits of a 64-bit memory address. `LPARAM` is a pointer-sized integer type, so no chopping will occur.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are using Delphi2009 or later.
In that case GetWindowText is Unicode and the Getmem should really be

```
GetMem(buffer, len*sizeof(char));
```

In the other case I guess you were lucky since you had a large enough buffer
reserved on the stack.